# How to add element to a list when it's async loaded from service via observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my page, I have two lists of *ngFor*'ed objects. One list is the assigned members, the other is assignable members. Both are shown by the following pattern.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="available$ | async as available">
  <div *ngFor="let item of available">
    <span (click)="assign(item)"</span>{{item.name}}
  </div>
</ng-container>

this.available$ = this.service.getMembers(false)
    .pipe(
      map(__ => ...), ... );
```

When I click on the assignable member, I want it to disappear from the list and appear in the other. I wonder how to go about achieving that without running *subscribe(...)* explicitly and assigning to the lists.

One way, would be saving the stuff to the server, then reloading the data but it seems like a huge overkill. another option is to have local, non-observable lists and managed them. However, I kind of like the *async* pipe and would prefer to keep the component code to the minimum. (Also, I have the whole loading/failure GUI set up based on the pipe in the page so it would be quite some work to rewrite.)

Comment: more code please

Comment: @devhedgehog Not sure for what purpose or which code. I created a minimal example as defined by the guidelines. Or at least, intended to, hehe. If I missed something that will make the question clearer, please let me know what that is and I'll do my best to provide the missing information.

Comment: I agree. Just Konrad if you could add a minimal repro on stackblitz that'd be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, what you want is to combine your service observable with the output from your assign function without having to use subscribe. I would suggest that you create a subject `$newMember` in your class that would emit the value of the new member you have as a result of your assign function. Thereafter you can do something like

```
this.available$ = combineLatest(this.service.getMembers(false), newMember$).pipe(map(...));
```

In the demo you can find the following:

```
    this.repos = combineLatest(
  this.http.get(this.path),
  this.itemObs.asObservable()
).pipe(
  map(([req, action]) => {
    switch (action.operation) {
      case "add": {

        return;
      }
      case "remove": {
        this.newReps = this.newReps.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
        return this.newReps;
      }
      default: {
        this.newReps = req["items"];
        return this.newReps;
      }
    }
  })
);
```

and your subscription will stay the same using the async pipe.

Here is a Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hw9kd5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

You need to have a look at the rxjs documentation now if you are wondering about the different operators.

`merge` - The output Observable only completes once all input Observables have completed. You will have to retrigger your request every time.

`combineLatest` -  Will emit a projection of the latest values for ALL inputs every time there is a new value for one of the inputs.

Moreover there are at least 15 operators that do this kind of merging of two or more streams with a slightly different behaviours. You just have to make sure to pick the one that fits best your case.

Comment: Interesting proposal. Just to verify, that won't make a new call to the backend from the service, right? It will reuse the already loaded value and amend the new one to it? How would I go about the converse thing? I.e. **removing** from the list (as opposed to amending to a list?

Comment: great answer, thumbs up

Comment: So the combineLatest will not call your backend a second time, but the $newMember observable needs to be a BehaviourSubject and not a Subject since combineLatest will fire only after both observables have emitted an initial value. I imagined and even simpler scenario than devhedgehog where all the functionality that you want like adding/deleting/editing would happen in the map since your only problem is actually getting to the point where you can work with the array... filtering is just one option.

Comment: @IvanMihaylov sure post your solution, I would like to see it

Comment: I liked his solution too. However, for some reason, merging, doesn't increase the list by the extra element. The output on the screen stays the same and subscribing to the assigned observable shows only the original elements.

Comment: Also, i just noticed a warning that *combineLatest* has been obsoleted and I'm supposed to pipe to map.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide you with a demo.

Comment: There's a slight glitch in the demo **but** it shows the principle of the approach and got me to the next step. So answer accepted and, definitely, +1 for the effort. If you take a peek at the other answer, based on *merge(...)*, do you have any thoughts on why it fails? Also, I'd suggest that you copy over a bigger chunk of the relevant code from your demo showing the setup done in the constructor. That's the part that got me to understanding the idea of your suggestion.

Comment: Ups, I have fixed the demo now.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if I get your question right but let me give it a try with pseudocode

```
import {merge, of, from, ...} from 'rxjs/operators';

assign(item){
 this.assigned = merge(this.assigned, of(item)); // add to list
 this.available = this.available.pipe(map(x => x.filter(y => y.id != item.id)); //remove from list
}
```

In case you might want to implement combileLatest solution provided by Ivan here is some pseudo code how to filter out deleted item from its list:

```
this.available$ = this.service.getMembers(false)
    .pipe(
      map(__ => ...),
      combineLatest(newMember.pipe(map(delItem => {action:"del", item = delItem}))
      filter(x => x[action] != 'del')));
```

something like this?

Comment: I prefer your suggestion. It seems so elegant. It doesn't work "as is" but we'll get there. WHat I noticed on my machine is that *item* needs to be bracketed (as it's a single instance and *of(...)* seems to require an array. After that - error's gone. However, the list on the screen doesn't update. I guess that I need to poke it somehow so that the subscribing iterator is notified about new value in the pipeline. Correct? When I subscribe to the result and print it out, it show only the original elements, though.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I am sorry I havent had much time lately to keep up to date with your question. Have your solved your issues using Ivan's solution?

Comment: No worry. I haven't resolved my issue with his solution because in the end, I realized it will be inadequate for our business case, as there are additional filterings and other rules prior to exposing the data on the screen, which I omitted to mention for the sake of to-the-point'ness. Never the less, his answer taught me how to use that method once the day when it's appropriate arrives. And in the end, I believe that's what you're asking, right? If, **and only if**, you feel you have time to invest, you're warmly welcome to give it another whack but I'm not stuck so it's up to you.